# Compiling Linux Kernel Error xt_CONNMARK.h

Tags: linux-kernel

I am attempting to compile the Linux 2.6.32.6 kernel with several modules built into the kernel for a very specific reason. I have included Root file system on NFS in an attempt to PXE Boot my own custom rescue Live-CD over LAN. After include the dependencies and module required for ROOT_NFS, I attempt to compile just the Linux kernel with `make bzImage`. When this runs I get the error

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target './linux-2.6.32.6/include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h', needed by './linux-2.6.32.6/usr/include/linux/netfilter/.install'. Stop.
```

Now I have tried disabling the Netfilter modules in the configuration and tried to find any dependencies that make require Netfilter, but this error still keeps occurring.

Any suggestions for resolving this error would be great.

Comment: You probably need to clean the `depends` for that file.  The *kbuild* should have picked up the fact you change the `.config`, but maybe not with this older version Linux.

Comment: Do a `make clean` first or manual remove the `Makefile` dependency information.  Your issue seems uncannily familiar, but I can't remember what the issue was.  It maybe related to `make O=...`.

Comment: After several attempts I removed the specific entry in the Kbuild. the strange thing however was there where 2 entries for `xt_CONNMARK.h`. The one that failed was all caps while the other one was all lower case. Ran into a few more cases with this but once I removed all the events(about 5 in total) the system compiled and booted properly.

Comment: @artlessnoise Any idea why this problem occurred? Was it intentional for something else?

Comment: I was doing something odd, I switch a file, manually edited `.config` or something like that.  It may have been compiler related.  The "C" files have `#include <xt_connmark.h>` and the file is named `xt_CONNMARK.h` or something like that.  Sorry, I can quite place it but I definitely had a similar sort of issue with that file.  The depends are generated auto-magically with `gcc`, so it may have made a mixed case depends rule, looking at the `#include` instead of the actual file opened.

Comment: @Blackninja543 I know this post has been a long time ago, but I have the same issue. If I remove the Makefile calls to the *.o files that are missing the*.c file the problem is solved?

Answer (score 13):

This is most likely because you have **lost some files** from your source tree due to being transferred through a filesystem which is case-insensitive.  There are approximately 15 different files in the Linux source tree from various times which are named the same, but have different capitalization.  This isn't normally a problem for people who build Linux kernels, because all reasonable filesystems are case-sensitive.

For those that are curious, the files that are this way are all in the netfilter tree - see `include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNTRACK.h` vs. `include/linux/netfilter/xt_conntrack.h` in v3.0 for example.

So, those files do exist, but you lost them.  Get a new source tree, unpack it on a case-sensitive filesystem and you won't have this error anymore.   Alternatively, copy the files from a "pristine" source tree or the [github mirror of the kernel](http://github.com/torvalds/linux) if you are afraid of losing modifications to your tree - they most likely aren't changed from release in the version you're compiling.

Comment: I still have this issue even after getting the Linux source code and checking out the v5.7 version. Still, some files are missing.